# How to open/show CellEditor of Alloy Datatable manually?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I'm writing a code , so that I can change column's editor manually . I'm able to set editor event on double click event ('dblClick') . 
When I click on cell, effect is observe on next click . 
What is missing ? 
Or
How can open/show editor manually ?

My code is like .......

```
table.delegate('dblclick', function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget; 
    var model = table.getRecord(target.get('id'));
    var type = model.get('type');
    var column = this.get('columns.value'); 
    column.editor = editors[type];
    this.showCellEditor(target); 
},'tr', table);
```

this.showCellEditor(target); --> this method is of YUI (Yahoo's UI) . Is any method is resemble to this one in Alloy UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting an editor on the fly, why not group similar data in the same column so that the same editor can be used?

```
var columns = [{
    editor: new Y.TextAreaCellEditor(),
    key: 'name'
}, {
    editor: new Y.DateCellEditor({
        dateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'
    }),
    key: 'birthday'
}];
```

If you group the data like that, then you can  change the [`editEvent`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DataTable.CellEditorSupport.html#attr_editEvent) of the dataTable to `dblclick` like so:

```
var dataTable = new Y.DataTable({
    // ...
    editEvent: 'dblclick'
}).render('#dataTable');
```

Here is a working example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-datatable', function(Y) {

  var columns = [{
    editor: new Y.TextAreaCellEditor(),
    key: 'name'
  }, {
    editor: new Y.DateCellEditor({
      dateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'
    }),
    key: 'birthday'
  }];

  var data = [{
    birthday: '9/9/1999',
    name: 'Jonathan Smithy'
  }, {
    birthday: '10/10/1990',
    name: 'Bob Duncan'
  }];

  var dataTable = new Y.DataTable({
    columnset: columns,
    recordset: data,
    editEvent: 'dblclick'
  }).render('#dataTable');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>


<div id="dataTable"></div>
```

If you must dynamically choose and display the editor, I'd recommend taking a look a the [`getEditor(record, column)`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DataTable.CellEditorSupport.html#method_getEditor) method of `A.DataTable.CellEditorSupport`. I was unable to get `getEditor()` to work, but I'd assume that if you can get it working, you could do something like `getEditor(data[1], column[0]).show()`.